# ¿Como hacer HEAD en vez de GET con libcurl?

Tags: c

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que `libcurl` no descargue la *url* sino únicamente las cabeceras *HTTP*?

Dependiendo de ellas quisiera decidir si mi programa descarga la *url*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pedir el HEAD de una url en *libcurl* hay que establecer la opción [`CURLOPT_NOBODY`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) = `1L`

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ejemplo.com");

  // esto hace que se utilize el verbo HEAD en lugar de GET
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* haz algo con las cabeceras... */

  // siempre liberar los recursos
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```